# How can I build a child object that uses InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE?

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, repository, persistence

I have a few objects that all are children on a single class. I am using the spring hibernate InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE to store them to a database.

I have a method that returns ANY CHILD object:

```
public Optional<? extends Product> getProductByID(long productId) {
        LOGGER.info("Returning product with ID: " + productId);
        return productDao.findById(productId);
    }
```

I know the what the object type will be as I have written the imports. How can I build a specific object and access the getters and setters specific to that child?

I can complete it using single separate methods with separate repositories:

```
public Optional<Cassette> getCassetteByID(long productId) {
        LOGGER.info("Getting Cassette with ID: {} from DB", productId);
        return cassetteDao.findById(productId);
    }
```

Is it possible to have a single method with an if statement instead?
Something like this:

```
public Optional<? extends Product> getProductByID(long productId) {
        LOGGER.info("Returning product with ID: " + productId);
        if (productId <= 4) {
            return brakeDao.findById(productId);
        } else if (productId <= 9) {
            return cassetteDao.findById(productId);
        } else {
            return productDao.findById(productId);
        }
    }
```

Sorry for the long winded question i wasn't quite sure how to frame the issue. I want to have the complete object so i can get specific data and change things as require.

Comment: No, you can't 'have a single method with an if statement' and 'access the getters and setters specific to that child', because the method call result type needs to be known and resolved at the *calling site*

Answer (score 0):

You could have a generified method, where you would at calling site specify, which type you expect. Something like:

```
public <T> Optional<T extends Product> getProductByID(long productId) {
        LOGGER.info("Returning product with ID: " + productId);
        Product result = productDao.findById(productId);
        if (result instance of T) return result;
        else return Optional.empty();
    }
```

On calling site you would then use:

```
Cassette received = myServiceClassInstance.<Cassette>getProductById(124);
```

Though this is probably in most cases not the preferred approach of doing things.
You could also switch by type of T to delegate to the specific Dao, but that's maybe even worse, cause changes in inheritance tree means you'd have to modify that switch.